# How to identify cell is merged cell with google sheets api using ptyhon

Tags: python, google-sheets, merge, google-sheets-api

I'm using Python API https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

I have a sheet looks like this and want to automate some cell filling logic

```
 |  A   |  B   |
--+------+------+
1 |  a1  |  b1  |
--+------+      |
2 |  a2  |      |
--+------+------+
3 |  a3  |  b2  |
--+------+------+
```

While using `readRange` = "A1:B" by

```
spreadsheet_id = 'my-spreadsheet-id'
ranges = []
include_grid_data = False  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges, includeGridData=include_grid_data)
response = request.execute()
pprint(response)
```

how can i retrieve the information of merge cells in a sheet using Sheets API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of merged cells are defined in the `merges` property of the sheet. From the code you posted, it would be: `response['sheets'][0]['merges']` (but with the necessary error code handling). It's worth noting that this will only show the merges in the specified range, not all of them.

### References

- [`merges` on Sheets (Sheets API reference)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#Sheet.FIELDS.merges)
- [Spreadsheets (Sheets API reference)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets)